# Fast way to find lists contains two particular items?

Tags: python

I have a list of lists (about 200) contains different strings:

```
lists = [
  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'g', ...],
  ['b', 'c', 'f', 'a', ...],
  ...
]
```

now I'd like to find out all the lists that contains two given strings, **in the given order**.

for example, given `('a', 'g')`, `['a', 'b', 'c', 'g', ...]` will be matched.

what's the pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: It is a trivial problem. This lacks any research effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the most Pythonic way would be:

```
selection = [L for L in lists
             if x1 in L and x2 in L and L.index(x1) < L.index(x2)]
```

the defect is that it will search each element twice, first to check the presence (forgetting the index) and second to check the ordering.

An alternative could be

```
def match(a, b, L):
    try:
        return L.index(a) < L.index(b)
    except ValueError:
        return False

selection = [L for L in lists if match(x1, x2, L)]
```

but I find it slightly uglier and I wouldn't use it unless performance is a problem.

If the logic required instead is to accept a list containing `[... x2 ... x1 ... x2 ...]` then the check is different:

```
selection = [L for L in lists
             if x1 in L and x2 in L[L.index(x1)+1:]]
```

that translated to english as "if x1 is in the list and x2 is the part following first x1" that also works as expected if `x1` and `x2` are the same value.

Comment: I agree `index` is the best way, but note that only the index of the first occurrence of the value is returned. So `match('h', 'k', ['a', 'k', 'h', 'k'])` returns `False` which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: @ajcr: You're right. I've added a version to handle that and also the case with `x1 == x2`.